# Can't add secondary index for dynamodb in cdk using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a dynamoDB table, with a secondary index with partition and sort key. 
I can create the table without the secondary index, but haven't been able to find a way yet to add the secondary index

I've looked at both of these resources, but haven't found anything that actually shows me what code i need in my cdk python script to create the resource with a secondary index
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-dynamodb-readme.html

This is the code that will create the table

```
table_name = 'event-table-name'
    event_table = dynamoDB.Table(self, 'EventsTable',
         table_name=table_name,
         partition_key=Attribute(
             name='composite',
             type=AttributeType.STRING
         ),
         sort_key=Attribute(
             name='switch_ref',
             type=AttributeType.STRING
         ),
         removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
         billing_mode=BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
         stream=StreamViewType.NEW_IMAGE,
                                 )
```

and this is the secondary index I need to attach to it

```
secondaryIndex = dynamoDB.GlobalSecondaryIndexProps(
        index_name='mpan-status-index',
        partition_key=Attribute(
            name='field1',
            type=AttributeType.STRING
        ),
        sort_key=Attribute(
            name='field2',
            type=AttributeType.STRING
        ),
    )
```

I've tried adding the block inside the table creation and tried calling the addSecondaryindex method on the table. But both fail either saying unexpected keyword or object has no attribute addGlobalSecondaryIndex

Answer (score 8):

addGlobalSecondaryIndex should be called on the Table class.

The code below (in typescript) works perfectly for me:

```
const table = new ddb.Table(this, "EventsTable", {
  tableName: "event-table-name",
  partitionKey: { name: 'composite', type: ddb.AttributeType.STRING },
  sortKey: { name: 'switch_ref', type: ddb.AttributeType.STRING },
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  billingMode: BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
  stream: StreamViewType.NEW_IMAGE
});
table.addGlobalSecondaryIndex({
  indexName: 'mpan-status-idex',
  partitionKey: { name: 'field1', type: ddb.AttributeType.STRING },
  sortKey:  { name: 'field2', type: ddb.AttributeType.STRING }
});
```

Comment: I was looking for a python solution. But thinking python simply isn't supported properly and i may need to simply use the typescript version

Comment: @Matt - Simply saying that Python uses underscore naming convention, so you have to use add_global_secondary_index(), not addGlobalSecondaryIndex(). It works well.

Comment: Way necro comment here - but it is worth noting that there is no language that CDK is in that 'isnt supported properly'. All sub languages outside of Typescript use a custom AWS interpreter to compile into TypesScript - which is why you can get Type errors from node in Python CDK and a custom construct can be written in any language and distributed for any language user of CDK to use. of course there can be bugs in that process, but regardless - the python version of CDK is derived directly from the Typescript version.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for this and stumbling on it through google search:

create your table with the usual:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_dynamodb as dynamodb
from aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb import Attribute, AttributeType, ProjectionType

table = dynamodb.Table(self, 'tableID',
                    partition_key=Attribute(name='partition_key', type = AttributeType.STRING))
```

then add your global secondary indexes in much the same way:

```
table.add_global_secondary_index( 
           partition_key=Attribute(name='index_hash_key', type=AttributeType.NUMBER),
           sort_key=Attribute(name='range_key', type=AttributeType.STRING),
           index_name='some_index')
```

you can add projection attributes with they kwarg arguments:

```
projection_type = ProjectionType.INCLUDE,
non_key_attributes= ['list', 'of', 'attribute','names']
```

and projection_type defaults to All if you don't include it.

I know the docs are incomplete in lots of areas, but this is found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/Table.html?highlight=add_global#aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb.Table.add_global_secondary_index

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the addGlobalSecondaryIndex method as in

```
event_table.addGlobalSecondaryIndex({indexName: "...", partitionKey: "...", ...})
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html#add-wbr-global-wbr-secondary-wbr-indexprops) for the method.

Comment: This simply returns 
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'addGlobalSecondaryIndex

Answer (score 0):

[aws_dynamodb.Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/Table.html) returns an [ITable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/ITable.html). To use the [addGlobalSecondaryIndex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb/Table.html#aws_cdk.aws_dynamodb.Table.add_global_secondary_index), first cast to `Table` like so:

```
table = aws_dynamodb.Table(self, "Table",
    partition_key=dynamodb.Attribute(name="id", type=dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING)

aws_dynamodb.Table(table).add_global_secondary_index(...)
```